# MVC Validate Sensitive information like ProjectId,UserIs etc?

Tags: html, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating one application using ASP.NET MVC 4.5/5.4.

i had model

```
public class user
{
prop string userId{ get; set;}
prop string email{ get; set;}
}
```

i am use it to view and taking userId in hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.userId)
```

and submit it back to server,and then after i m updating user email
but mean a while if user change hidden field value of userid then its obviously going to do some adverse effect in server side.
So my question is how to prevent those kind of attack and store sensitive information in view ?

Appriciate guys,
Thanks&Regards

Comment: Never ever trust user input !!!.

Answer (score 1):

> and store sensitive information in view ?

By not storing any sensitive information in your views. Sensitive information should live on the server. For example in a database or something.

Another possibility is to validate on the server that the ProjectId belongs to the currently authenticated user by querying your database. Obviously the currently authenticated user should be retrieved from the forms authentication module and absolutely never be part of any hidden fields. That's the only thing you could trust -> the currently authenticated user which is retrieved from the forms authentication cookie in a secure way. Once you know the user you could query your database to verify whether the input he provided (things like ProjectIds, etc...) really belong to him. This way if the user attempts to tamper with this information the validation will fail and you will greet him with the corresponding error message.